# java struts2 very strange behaviour while using iterator

Tags: struts2

```
public class UserAction{
 private UserData user;
 //getter, setter
  public String Load() {
        user = UserDao.getInstance().getItem(getUserContext().getId()); 
        request.getSession().setAttribute("item", user);
        return super.Load();
    }
} 

public class PropertyAction {
    private List <PropertyData> propertyList;
    //getter, setter
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        propertyList=PropertyDao.getInstance().getItems();
        return "list";
    }
}
```

jsp:

```
<s:iterator value="propertyList" var="item">
    ${item.name}
    ${item.thema}
    ${item.desc}
</s:iterator>
```

I want to show very strange behaviour of Struts2.

1. I click property link -> then run PropertyAction.execute() and it display above jsp.
2. I click user link -> then run UserAction.Load()
3. I click property link -> then run PropertyAction.execute() and error has been shown "UserData has no property thema".

I spy what happened and I notice that I set setAttribute with name "item". So if I use var="item" in my iterator in jsp,  it doesn not use value from propertyList but from session !

My question is it is correct behaviour  ?

Answer (score 0):

This is defined behavior; whether or not it's "correct" is debatable.

Because you're using JSP EL, the Struts request wrapper is responsible for resolving JSP EL expressions. The normal application scopes are searched first (e.g., application, session, request). If nothing is found, only then will the value stack be queried for matching expressions.

If you accessed `item` via non-JSP EL means, e.g., the `<s:property>` tag, only the value stack would be queried, and you'd get the expected behavior.

When you mix ELs results are not always what you'd expect, so you must be aware how the frameworks in question relate to each other.